# What is a word that means "something that is commonly known, but not commonly talked about"?

Tags: single-word-requests

For example, nobody likes to use the restroom after they take a shower because you slide around on the seat, but that's not something commonly talked about between persons.

Or the well understood, but un-discussed feeling you get when you feel a bug or something crawling on you before you fall asleep, even though you know it's not a bug, but just a sensation.

*It could not be of English origin.*

Comment: Questions on choosing an ideal word or phrase must include information on how it will be used in order to be answered. For help writing a good word or phrase request, see: About single word requests

Comment: Are you looking to describe something we actively avoid discussing e.g. because it's embarrassing? Or are you trying to describe something we simply don't think to talk about because it seems unimportant?

Comment: Some aren't really sure it's _just_ a [sensation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delusional_parasitosis). I suggest **unspeackables** or **moot points** considering that these are not worth talking about.

Comment: "Apparently '*mokita*' is a Kilivila word, from the language spoken on Kirwinia, the largest of the Trobriand Islands, in New Guinea". 

Unfortunately can't find a reliable source to confirm this info

Answer (score 44):

**Open secret** — [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/open+secret)

> *noun* a supposedly secret but generally known matter
>
> *"It's an open secret that he's been cheating on his wife."*

Open secret — [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_secret)

> An open secret is a concept or idea that is "officially" secret or restricted in knowledge but is actually widely known; or it refers to something that is widely known to be true but which none of the people most intimately concerned is willing to categorically acknowledge in public.

Comment: It may not be a single word, but hope this fits.

Comment: I don't think this really fits because the examples @Ashley gives aren't even supposed to be secrets.

Comment: @NowIGetToLearnWhatAHeadIs - that's the point of the phrase; the open part is that everyone knows and the secret part is that no-one talks about it. It is in fact the most appropriate phrase for the OP's question.

Comment: @Spratty I feel like 5arx's answer is more appropriate for the OP's questions.

Comment: @AXMIM at the end of the day I suppose it's down to personal preference. I'm personally more familiar and comfortable with "open secrets" so I suppose I'm always going to lean that way, despite "unspoken truths" being a perfectly good answer.

Answer (score 25):

It's not single-word, but there's a good fit in **common knowledge**.

> something that is known to many people but often not made known officially

[Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/common-knowledge)

Answer (score 18):

As you say "It could not be of English origin", the adjective **taboo** comes to mind.

> late 18th century: from Tongan tabu ‘set apart, forbidden’; introduced
> into English by Captain Cook.

Definition: "not acceptable to talk about or do" (Mirriam Webster)

examples:

> Filipina helper Liz (not her real name) battled bed bugs in June 2012
> in Tai Wong Street in Wan Chai. She says the pests covered the 500 sq
> ft hostel, which was home to 10 helpers. "They were on the walls, on
> my towels and on the carpet." Travellers also spread the problem. Bed
> bugs are a bigger issue in hotels than the industry will admit.
> "People don't talk about it because it's **taboo**, but it's definitely
> happening"
> http://www.scmp.com/lifestyle/health/article/1402401/bed-bug-infestations-are-rise-and-pests-are-hard-kill
>
> Get kids talking about the loo, say NGOs, and it will help break down
> a major barrier to education in the developing world: cultural **taboos**
> about sanitation.
> https://www.theguardian.com/global-development-professionals-network/2015/nov/19/reading-writing-and-sanitation-how-kids-are-key-to-ending-toilet-taboos

Comment: what exactly is "taboo" about OP's example? It's not taboo to feel like ants are crawling over your skin.

Comment: @V0ight - you might feel that there are ants crawling over your skin but not **talk about** it (as in the title of the question) because it is taboo.

Comment: ~ you've failed to explain what is taboo about not talking about ants crawling on your skin. Taboo is used in contexts of something that is *bad*, i.e. socially unacceptable

Comment: In his specific example, what's taboo is that it's a discussion of using the toilet. :p (That said, I'm not sure whether that was *supposed* to be a relevant part of the example.)

Comment: In the example of the bug sensation, personally I would have no problem talking about it. Reading between the lines I interpreted that for the OP this topic is taboo because it might demonstrate paranoia or suggest dirty living conditions?

Comment: It's not "forbidden" to talk about sliding on the toilet or feeling bugs that don't exist. It's embarrassing and awkward, but if you do talk about it you won't be shunned. The word *taboo* is reserved for things on the order of cannibalism and incest - acts which would get someone actively shunned from most other people in their culture. This is what makes something forbidden, and not simply uncomfortable.

Comment: @talrnu, your definition of taboo is too strict. The simple definition given by Mirriam Webster is "not acceptable to talk about or do".

Comment: @grateful I maintain that none of the asker's examples are "not acceptable" by the same logic, even if the term "forbidden" in your own answer doesn't suit you. I'll also refer you to Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taboo#Examples) as this is a discussion of what qualifies as "taboo", more than a few words in definition are necessary.

Comment: I'll also point out that your examples do nothing to demonstrate the meaning of the word, only to show it in use. You could replace the word "taboo" with any other adjective in your examples and the nature of the noun they're describing would be no clearer without knowing the definition of the adjective.

Comment: @talrnu, see this example of the use of the word taboo: "Filipina helper Liz (not her real name) battled bed bugs in June 2012 in Tai Wong Street in Wan Chai. She says the pests covered the 500 sq ft hostel, which was home to 10 helpers. "They were on the walls, on my towels and on the carpet." Travellers also spread the problem. Bed bugs are a bigger issue in hotels than the industry will admit. "People don't talk about it because it's taboo, but it's definitely happening"  http://www.scmp.com/lifestyle/health/article/1402401/bed-bug-infestations-are-rise-and-pests-are-hard-kill

Comment: @talrnu This was the first reference I found upon googling "taboo bug". This site is called English Language and **Usage** - mine is a valid example of usage and the kind of usage that I had in mind when I wrote my answer. Besides, the words are almost certainly the words of the author - experienced, native English speaking journalist Jasper Moiseiwitsch, currently
Deputy Editor of Market Talk Asia at Dow Jones - so don't be such a snob.

Comment: The word is used in a quotation, so unless you're accusing the author of misquoting their interviewee, the author's credentials are irrelevant. This example is as valuable as if I told you my friend Joe said "I talk about bedbugs all the time because they're not taboo." Granted, I'm not a reputable journalist, so I might be lying.

Answer (score 15):

[**unspoken truth**](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22unspoken+truths%22&oq=%22unspoken+truths%22&aqs=chrome..69i57.381440j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) (thanks be to @hatchet)

Also, as a variation on the term **unspoken rule**, [we could coin the phrase **unspoken culture**](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22unspoken+truths%22&oq=%22unspoken+truths%22&aqs=chrome..69i57.381440j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=%22unspoken+culture%22).

---

Finally, Carl Jung's **collective unconscious** seems apt here.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collective_unconscious)

> According to Jung, the human collective unconscious is populated by instincts and by archetypes: universal symbols such as the Great Mother, the Wise Old Man, the Shadow, the Tower, Water, the Tree of Life, and many more.
>
> Jung considered the collective unconscious to underpin and surround the unconscious mind, distinguishing it from the personal unconscious of Freudian psychoanalysis. He argued that the collective unconscious had profound influence on the lives of individuals, who lived out its symbols and clothed them in meaning through their experiences. The psychotherapeutic practice of analytical psychology revolves around examining the patient's relationship to the collective unconscious.

Comment: Hah, I feel this is the only answer that really understood the question.  But I still wish there were a better word to use in this context.

Comment: @Darren Ringer ~ Thank you :) .... Let's make one up then !

Answer (score 12):

> **Tacit** \Tac"it\, a. [L. *tacitus*, p. p. of *tacere* to be silent, to
>        pass over in silence; akin to Goth. [*thorn]ahan* to be silent,
>        Icel. *[thorn]egja*, OHG. *dag[=e]n*: cf. F. *tacite*. Cf.
>        {Reticent}.]
>        Done or made in silence; implied, but not expressed; silent;
>        as, tacit consent is consent by silence, or by not
>        interposing an objection. -- {Tac"it*ly}, adv.
>        [1913 Webster]
>
> ```
>        The tacit and secret theft of abusing our brother in
>        civil contracts.                         --Jer. Taylor.
>  [1913 Webster]
> ```

Answer (score 10):

Perhaps narrower than you are looking for, but [**unmentionable**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unmentionable) comes to mind. Unmentionable typically connotes the subject is well known, but not spoken about, due to embarrassing or offensive aspects.

I say "perhaps narrower" because your question doesn't limit the lack of discussion as being due to an embarrassing or offensive characteristic.

Comment: "unmentionables" was (is?) commonly used to refer to underwear specifically, and could generally be used for things like OP mentions.  (Commentary - the internet has really allowed for people to check on things like OP.)

Answer (score 2):

I'm at a loss for a single word, but this type of thing is commonly described as "something people don't talk about." "Something people don't talk about" isn't necessarily taboo; it's just considered unpleasant, uncomfortable, or rude to discuss with others, though there is an unspoken, implicit understanding that most people have knowledge of or experience with the unmentioned "something."

As a single word, I would refer to the "something people don't talk about" as an [unpleasantness](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/unpleasantness), though by definition it isn't *necessarily* "something people don't talk about."

Example:

> The **unpleasantness** of accidentally getting poop on your hand when changing a baby's diaper is **something people don't** (usually) **talk about**.

Answer (score 1):

Your examples seem different to me.

> For example, nobody likes to use the restroom after they take a shower because you slide around on the seat, but that's not something commonly talked about between persons.

I would say that's probably considered **impolite** to discuss, like the details of your bowel movements. You probably wouldn't discuss it at a business meeting or the dinner table, but you might with your doctor. ("I sprained my wrist when I slipped off the toilet...")

> Or the well understood, but un-discussed feeling you get when you feel a bug or something crawling on you before you fall asleep, even though you know it's not a bug, but just a sensation.

I don't know of any social barrier to talking about that; it just might not be interesting enough.

Comment: Hi this doesn't appear to be an answer. Did you mean to make a comment instead?

Comment: This answer was automatically flagged as low-quality because of its length and content.
Do not answer questions which should be closed. Questions which lack results of research are out of scope. Word or phrase requests are out of scope, unless they are expert-level, particularly interesting, unique, and thought-provoking, and show effort and research.

Answer (score 1):

The reasons why people shy away from discussing such topics vary, so corralling all of them into a single term is challenging. [grateful](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/185799/grateful) mentioned **taboo** in [another answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/339258/9604). Other broad terms for subjects that may make others uneasy are **rude** or **gauche**.

“Toilet humor” is not discussed in polite company because it is considered **tacky**. Sex jokes and objectifying humor are **off-color**, **crude**, or **obnoxious**. We don’t generally announce the results of colonoscopies to or share unedited, graphic birth videos with mere acquaintances because the topics are **uncomfortable** or **awkward**.  Revealing one’s exact income to someone whom the speaker has not engaged in an accounting or legal capacity is seen as **boastful**, **unfiltered**, or—itself crudely characterized—**douchey**.

The last is interesting because it is borrowed from an **unmentionable** (also [mentioned in another answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/339268/9604)) bathroom subject as a pejorative for immoderate behavior.